# is it possible to config nginx certificate in public file

Tags: nginx

Now this is my nginx server config:

```
server{
    listen 443;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.com/fullchain1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.com/privkey1.pem;

    server_name super.example.com;
    #rewrite ^(.*)$ https://${server_name}$1 permanent;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/pc-super-frontend-fat;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ^~ /service/ {
        proxy_pass  http://k8s-edge-node/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

in every server config file, it contains certificate config:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.com/fullchain1.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.com/privkey1.pem;
```

because I have more than 50 sub domains, if change the certificate, it should change more than 100 files config(80 + 443). is it possible to make the certificate config to a seperate file and just reference it in server config file?

Comment: u may use a single cert which contains all subdomains

Comment: Define `change the certificate`. If you renew the certificate - it will still use the same filename, right ?

Comment: I want to define the conifg in one place, so that if I change config, I modify one places @IVOGELOV

Comment: If all 50 subdomains use the same configuration, then you do not need 50 `server` blocks - you can make use of regex like `server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.example\.com$;` and then `ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/$subdomain/fullchain1.pem;`